# Configuring the Hidden Settings in Windows ICD

Tags: windows-10, windows-installation, answerfile

There are quite a few Hidden Settings in Windows 10 ICD that I want to configure. I know that I can insert them manually into the customizations.xml file, but it's difficult to find any information on what the correct child nodes are. Specifically, I want to configure the battery settings, as listed on

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/mt622170(v=vs.85).aspx

I've tried using the child node names listed on each page for the Windows Provisioning line, but none of them are valid child nodes according to Windows ICD. Can you tell me what the correct node names are?

I've tried:

```
<Battery>
  <CriticalAction>3</CriticalAction>
  <CriticalBatteryLevel>5</CriticalBatteryLevel>
  <LowAction>0</LowAction>
  <LowBatteryLevel>10</LowBatteryLevel>
  <LowBatteryWarning>0</LowBatteryWarning>
  <ReserveBatteryLevel>4</ReserveBatteryLevel>
</Battery>
```

On a side note, and as a semi-rhetorical question, why are there hidden settings? Considering ICD is used by developers to customize an installation, why aren't all settings visible?

Note: I have the above xml excerpt nested under Settings-Customizations-Common-Power-Policy-Settings

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone stumbles across this with the same problem, this solution seems to work: (the other scheme alias names I have are "HighPerformance" and "PowerSaver")

```
<Power>
<Policy>
<Settings>
<Battery>
<SchemePersonality>
<Default SchemeAlias="Balanced">
        <Setting>
        <CriticalAction>
            <AcValue>3</AcValue>
            <DcValue>3</DcValue>
        </CriticalAction>
        <CriticalBatteryLevel>
            <AcValue>5</AcValue>
            <DcValue>5</DcValue>
        </CriticalBatteryLevel>
        <LowAction>
            <AcValue>0</AcValue>
            <DcValue>0</DcValue>
        </LowAction>
        <LowBatteryLevel>
            <AcValue>10</AcValue>
            <DcValue>10</DcValue>
        </LowBatteryLevel>
        <LowBatteryWarning>
            <AcValue>0</AcValue>
            <DcValue>0</DcValue>
        </LowBatteryWarning>
        <ReserveBatteryLevel>
            <AcValue>4</AcValue>
            <DcValue>4</DcValue>
        </ReserveBatteryLevel>
        </Setting>
</Default>
</SchemePersonality>              
</Battery>
</Settings>
</Policy>
</Power>
```